# Matrix Orthogonal to Vector: why take transpose?

Tags: least-squares, econometrics, matrix, linear-algebra

In econometrics, we often have n observations (in a column vector $y$) which we want to explain with k$<$n regressors (the observations are in an nxk matrix $X$). In this case we use least squares estimation and we can uniquely write the observation as a sum of a fitted value $\hat{y}\in C(x)$ and a residual $\hat{\epsilon} \notin C(X)$, where $C(X)$ is the column span of X: $y = \hat{y} +\hat{\epsilon}$

In this case we have $$X^T\hat{\epsilon} = 0$$
which expresses "othogonality". My question is, **Where does the transpose on $X$ come from?** The above form is very reminiscent of that of the orthogonality of two column vectors defined by the inner product: $<x,y> = x^Ty = 0$, but I have never seen "the inner product" of matrices defined and when we multiply matrices we never need to take the transpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The equation $X^\top \epsilon = 0$ is simply matrix shorthand for the system of equations
$$
\begin{align}
x_1^\top \epsilon & = 0 \\
& \vdots \\
x_n^\top \epsilon & = 0 \\
\end{align}
$$
where $x_i$ is a vector in $\mathbb{R}^n$ representing the $i$th column of the design matrix $X$. This system encodes the constraint that each feature vector be orthogonal to the residual vector.